# [cobalt]Automatically YouTube video goes to Pause Mode

Tags: cobalt

When we execute 12H Endurance test from YouTube 2019 Manual test link  video goes to pause mode after playing some videos in the playlist and  we can see the popup saying “…paused. Continue watching?” We are assuming it is coming from YouTube app. Is the network connection loss the only possible reason for this popup, or can it be triggered by something else such as player error? , On pressing remote UP key playback resumed.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not Cobalt-specific. Please contact your YouTube account manager for more information.